# Highcharts- Tooltips don't delete permanently

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to delete tooltips as they are not necessary for my case. I tried to delete them but they still keep appearing. Is there a problem with the cache? is there something I can try? See code below (with tooltips) but as I said deleting them doesn't work as they still show up. TIA

```
enter code here
```

https://jsfiddle.net/srduscea/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just disable tooltips with the following code,

```
tooltip:  
       { enabled: false },
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/xob6wh0n/)**